# Android Intent getting NULL

Tags: android, android-intent, null

In my app i used following,

```
        String launch = rowItems.get(position).getApplauncher().toString();

        Intent in = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                launch);

        System.out.println("lauch=" + launch);
        System.out.println("intent=" + in);
        startActivity(in);
```

in that i got launch String properly it **not null**

but after that pass it in Intent, Intent print **null**

I also try using **Intent in = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                    getPackageName());

**it work ok, and it not null,**
then why my String intent getting null,
my string intent on System.out.println printed as following (in logcat ):

```
   I/System.out(3323): lauch=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=  

   [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.android.speechrecorder
   cmp=com.android.speechrecorder/.SpeechRecorderActivity }

   I/System.out(3323): intent=null   // but here got null
```

why it null ? and how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

> why it null ?

Not every package installed on the device has a launcher activity.

> and how to solve this ?

Check for `null` and handle it appropriately. Or, solve your problem in some other way. For example, if you are writing a home screen-style launcher, you should be using `queryIntentActivities()` on a `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `Intent` to find the launchable activities.